# Classic ASP - Page state not changing

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I'm working on a site (that's written in classic asp) and it seems that on alot of pages, where certain buttons caused the page to postback to itself. The contents on the page seem to remain the same, even after it shouldn't. For example a row in a table should dissapear.

However, when I refresh the page without posting back again. (Just revisiting no re-posting) the contents changes. This just happens in Firefox and not in IE. Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: "This just happens in Firefox and not in IE."  Not an ASP issue if it only happens in one browser.  ASP runs on the server.  Check your browser settings for caching as mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the actual code, nothing more than a guess could be made.

Is it maybe a browser caching issue?

Make sure the pages have the following in them before any content is written to the page:

```
<%

response.expires = 0
response.addheader "Pragma", "no-cache"
response.addheader "Cache-Control", "no-cache"
%>
```

Comment: Unlikely that a POST would have caching problems

Answer (score 1):

Check your HTML. I have the same problem with Firefox if the FORM-Tag is inside the TABLE Tag AND Html is added to TABLE after pageload per Javascript. This results in that not all input parameters are sent.

**Not working in FF**

```
<table>
<form>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</form>
</table>
```

**Working in FF**

```
<form>
<table>
<tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```